# PHP CURL_Multi checking status of finished handles, removing, adding, timeouts

Tags: php, multithreading, curl-multi

So I am processing up to about 3000 links, I am using curl_multi to speed up the process. I used a simple process of 20 at a time, wait for all 20 to finish, process 20 more type of method, but I know this is inefficient, especially if one of those 20 links takes forever to download. So I need to know how to write a loop that goes through all 3000 links by adding/removing handles as soon as I get the contents from that url.

I am using a few of these fundamentals:

```
define('RUNATONCE', 20); // Links to process at a time

// My URL holding multi-dimensional array:
// This first dimension is about 1000 and the second dimension is 3
$allurls[0][0];
```

I need to be able to:

1) Check when a handle is done, and to know to which url in my multidimensional array that handle belongs

2) Retrieve the contents of that handle and assign a process based on whether that handle's contents is part of `$allurls[0][0],$allurls[0][1]`, or `$allurls[0][2]` (different process for each of those)

3) Remove that handle and add another URL from `$allurls` until all links have been processed

4) Process a manual time out on any URL that has been taking more than a certain amount of time, say 2 minutes (because `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` & `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` do not work properly in a curl_multi environment (or at least that is my experience and understanding based on http://curl.haxx.se/mail/curlphp-2008-06/0006.html )), but I also need to know in my `$allurls` if that URL timed out...

I know this seems like a bit of work, but for someone who knows this, it shouldn't be that much work... I just don't really know the specifics of how to do it... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation where I needed to validate certain URLs and the two solutions I found were first to make PHP fork a new process using [pcntl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) if it is installed or (and this is ugly, but unfortunately what I settled for since pcntl isn't installed on the server) use AJAX to request the PHP page that validates the URL. I have the timeout set to 30 seconds, so even if something is taking a long time, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Have you tried just writing a simple PHP script that does one at a time and doing all the forks in `bash`?  Each loop you just count the number of processes if its less than your max you pull the next url.  If you have to do this with PHP then disregard the suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too, however my host has `shell_exec` and related functions disabled. That's a good idea though if it's possible.